# Can you inherit from a contract already deployed to the blockchain?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

So instead of doing something like:

```
contract Parent {
...
}

contract Child is Parent {
...
}
```

Can the Parent be declared referencing an already deployed contract?

```
contract Parent = 0x123123123...

contract Child is Parent {
...
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the compiler cannot determine the ABI of the `Parent` contract from the bytecode on the blockchain, so this will not work.

Comment: Would it be even theoretically possible to make a compiler that could determine ABI from the parent or that ABI is passed to the compiler so it can reuse deployed bytecode. Thinking about millions of the same smart contracts deployed over and over, so same bytecode is used so many times and clogs up the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you might be able to repurpose an existing contract as described [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3850/16) I guess this might work with some work-arounds. I think this would be very interesting to explore but cannot give details.

Comment: I'm sorry, it appears that you've got a typo on the "as described here" link.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.rulerprotocol.com/
This protocol continuously issues new tokens which have the same behavior (same functions), and only different names. In its  [implementation](https://github.com/Ruler-Protocol/ruler-core-public/blob/1156cd52147efffb8cbd68508875010ef31acc38/contracts/RulerCore.sol#L448) , it clones a parent token using [`library Clones`](https://github.com/Ruler-Protocol/ruler-core-public/blob/1156cd52147efffb8cbd68508875010ef31acc38/contracts/utils/Clones.sol#L24), which interacts with the Ethereum Virtual Machine using inline assembly.

Comment: It just creates a proxy targeting the deployed contract, it doesn't add extra functionality to consider as inheritance.

Comment: Like Ismael pointed out, this isn't a case of inheritance from a deployed contract